# XSL: Only copy nodes which have a duplicate attribute value in a large XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

Here is the type of input I have:

```
<modifs>
   <test>
      <ref id="1"/>
      <ref id="2"/>
      <ref id="800"/>
      <ref id="5000"/>
      <ref id="10000"/>
      <ref id="40000"/>
   </test>
   <modif id="1">content1</modif>
   <modif id="2">content2</modif>
   <modif id="3">content3</modif>
   <modif id="4">content4</modif>
</modifs>
```

In this input, the first list "ref" is just a list of attributes, and the second list "modif" is what really matters to me.
What I would want to do is to display only the "modif" nodes which have a matching "id" attribute in the "ref" list: here what I would get is just this:

```
<modif>
    <modif id="1">content1</modif>
    <modif id="2">content2</modif>
</modifs>
```

I made an attempt to deal with this, which was partly successful. What I did was to check, for every @id of a "modif" node if there was a preceding matching "ref"@id:

```
  <xsl:template match="modifs">
    <xsl:for-each select="./modif">
      <xsl:if test="./@id=preceding::ids/id">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

However, I'm currently working on a very large XML file (200k+ ids), and this method is not time efficient at all (works well for the first thousand ids, takes hours/days after that).
I'm pretty sure there's a way around it (with muenchian grouping?) but I really don't understand what I'm supposed to do...

If someone could give me a hand / explain how I should proceed, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need muenchian grouping here, although you could do with using a key to look up whether the `ref` elements exist

```
  <xsl:key name="ref" match="ref" use="@id" />
```

Then, used in conjunction with the [XSLT identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), you just need a template to match the `modif` elements with no corresponding `ref` element

```
<xsl:template match="modif[not(key('ref', @id))]"/>
```

Try this XSLT instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="ref" match="ref" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="modif[not(key('ref', @id))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="test" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, however it doesn't seem to work as I get an empty output. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tested my XSLT at http://www.xslfiddle.net/. When I paste in the XML from your question, and the XSLT in my answer, it does produce the output you require. How are you actually performing the transformation?

Comment: I have thought of something. In your actual XML, do you have a `test` element somewhere else, possibly as an parent, or ancestor, of `modifs`?

Comment: I reprocessed it and it worked this time, I must have done something wrong yesterday, sorry about that. Even if it still takes quite long to go through my whole input ( 3-4 minutes for 1/5 of the original file: I divided it in order to be quicker), it is way better than it was with my previous attempt.

Comment: I proposed a minor edit of your solution: the strip-space instruction. As mentioned in the title I'm working on a large XML file, and each modif element with no corresponding ref element was generating useless empty space.

Comment: I have approved your edit. I usually put `strip-space` in, but neglected to in this instance. Without it, the identity template will copy the white space nodes that occur either side of the `modif` that gets removed.